# Mostrar resultado de la consulta en input text

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un script JQuery que consulta la base de datos dependiendo de una variable de un `select`, que consulta y trae los resultados.

Actualmente lo muestra en un `select` como parte de un combobox, pero ahora quiero que lo muestre en un `input` tipo texto para generar un código adicional.

No encuentro la forma, solamente muestra la información en un `div` y en el `select`, no es lo que quiero.

**Aqui el script**:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span class="bigger-80">Tipo Material</span>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="famid" name="famid" >
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span class="bigger-80">Sub-Tipo Material</span>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tipoid" name="tipoid" >
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mateid").change(function(){
    $.get("core/controlador/getFamilia.php","mateid="+$("#mateid").val(), function(data){
      $("#famid").html(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>

<?php //getFamilia.php
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','materiales');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblmaterialsub WHERE material=$_GET[mateid]");

while($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $material=$row['letrasub'];
  print $material;
}
?>
```

Mil gracias por la ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberás ocupar el método val<sup>1</sup> de *JQuery* que modifica el atributo `value` de los `inputs` de este modo:

- Primero obtienes el nodo con la sintaxis de `$('elemento')`
- Segundo ese elemento que obtuviste lo asignas a una variable le modificas su value con el método ya mencionado

Código de ejemplo:

```
let caja = $("#caja")
caja.val("123")
```

El método `val()` es el equivalente en *JavaScript plano* de la propiedad `value`

**EJEMPLO**

En el siguiente script obtengo el input a través de su `id` y modifico su atributo `value` con ayuda del método `val()`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="caja">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        let cajaTexto = $("#caja")
        cajaTexto.val(new Date())
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tu código me parece debería quedar así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mateid").change(function(){
    $.get("core/controlador/getFamilia.php","mateid="+$("#mateid").val(), function(data){
      $("#famid").val(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[val method](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Podrías adaptar el script por favor con referencia al que se coloca? Gracias

Comment: @FranklinTaylhardat es decir quieres el ejemplo completo?

Comment: solo el script jquery donde hago la consulta a getFamilia.php para traer los resultados. Si no es mucho pedir claro.

Comment: @FranklinTaylhardat checa si lo que puse ye sirve

Comment: Excelente, solamente que le cambié $("#famid").val(data), por $(".famid").val(data), y ahora si funciona. Mil gracias por la gran ayuda.